# Have to call wx.Panel twice to set the correct size

Tags: python, wxpython

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Test',size=wx.Size(500,500))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1,pos=(20,40),size=wx.Size(10,500))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1,size=wx.Size(500,10))
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This code will create two panel objects inside the same window.
If either line of wx.Panel call is deleted, the other panel will not have the correct size and it will fill up the entire frame.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation of [`wx.Frame`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Frame.html):

> `wx.Frame` processes the following events:
>   - `wxEVT_SIZE`: if the frame has **exactly one child** window, not counting the status and toolbar, **this child is resized to take the entire frame client area**. [...]

You can define your own [Sizers](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/sizers_overview.html#sizers-overview) to specify a different behavior:

```py
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Test',size=wx.Size(500,500))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1,size=wx.Size(500,10))
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        self.Show()
```